# How to create interprocess file access mutex in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, mutex

I have two processes reading/writing same files. So I wanna create a lock between them. My idea is to create a file in that folder named file.lock containing the process identification information. The process which has the lock creates the file and releases the lock by deleting it.
My question is:

1. Is it possible that while process A is creating the file and before the file is eventually created, process B checks the file and finds that it's not there, and thus the mutex fails?
2. How can `wait()` method be implemented in this scenario?

Comment: I think it is better to use rdbms instead of file for distributed locking.

Comment: Using a database is not always the best option, particularly for simple problems.

Comment: @GregS In some cases I would say it's fine to add additional information as an edit. I guess it would depend on the extent of the changes. A new paragraph at the end is one thing; a complete re-write is clearly not good.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to look into the [`FileLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) API.